# nginx rewrite to add a subdomain in url without redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite below url **without redirect**.

From: **example.com/group/abc/**
To: **group.example.com/abc/**

I would still like to keep the example.com/group/abc/ in users browser url.

I have tried below NGINX configuration but it does not prevent it from redirect because of http or https.

[Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) says: If a replacement string starts with “http://”, “https://”, or “$scheme”, the processing stops and the redirect is returned to a client.

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name  ~^(?<group>.*)\.example\.com$;

  location / {
    # Existing settings
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;

    proxy_pass          http://localhost:8090;

    # My addition
    if ($group = "") {
      rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.$host/$2 break;
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried `rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.$host/$2 last;`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a service on `localhost:8090` that responds to requests formatted like: `//group.example.com/abc/`.

The reverse proxy also receives requests formatted like `//example.com/group/abc/` which require changing before being passed upstream to `localhost:8090`.

1. I would suggest that you use two `server` blocks, one for handling requests to `example.com` and another for everything else.
2. `localhost:8090` receives the request in two parts. Importantly, the domain name part is passed to it in the `proxy_set_header Host` value.
3. You cannot change the domain name with `rewrite` (unless you are using it perform an external redirect), but you **can** use `rewrite` to change the part of URL *after the domain name*, before it's sent upstream.

For example:

```
server {
  ...
  server_name *.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;

    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8090;
  }
}
server {
  ...
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2 break;

    proxy_set_header Host $1.$http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;

    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8090;
  }
}
```

Notice that we capture the group name in `$1` using `rewrite` in `$1`, but use it later in the `proxy_set_header Host` statement to recreate the subdomain name. In the example above, `$1.$http_host` is used, but `$1.example.com` also works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Richard. I will test this configuration and provide further details here.

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host $1.$http_host` did the magic. Thank you.